# How to fix amcharts zoom reset on data reload

Tags: reactjs, amcharts, amcharts4

I use amcharts 4 and when the data reloads, it resets the zoom level. How do I prevent this? I have two timeouts, but I don't think they are causing the problem because I tried removing them and the problem was still there.

I assume the problem is caused by how I initiated or set my axes, but couldn't fix it by myself.

One other reason can be the way I used parseended event.

Here is my code:

```
componentDidMount = () => {

    setTimeout(() => {
        try {
            const {onChangeSettings, widgetData, token} = this.props;

            let chart = am4core.create(this.state.key, am4charts.XYChart);

            chart.padding(0, 30, 0, 0);

            chart.dataSource.requestOptions.requestHeaders = [
                {
                    'key': 'Authorization',
                    'value': token
                }
            ];

            let title = chart
                .titles
                .create();
            title.text = widgetData.graph.name;
            title.fontSize = 17;
            title.fontFamily = "Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif";

            chart.dataSource.parser.options.dateFormat = 'i';
            chart.preloader.disabled = true;
            chart.dataSource.keepCount = true;
            chart.dataSource.disableCache = true;

            if (widgetData.graph.time_range.last) {
                chart.dataSource.url = `${DashboardApi
                    .service_url}/bus?method=${widgetData
                    .graph
                    .data_type}&interval=${widgetData
                    .graph
                    .data_range}&ids=${widgetData
                    .measurements
                    .map(m => m.id)
                    .join(',')}&from=${moment(new Date(new Date().getTime() - timeEnum[widgetData.graph.time_range.range] * widgetData.graph.time_range.time))
                    .format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]')}&to=${moment(new Date())
                    .format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]')}&offset=0&count=20`;
            } else {
                chart.dataSource.url = `${DashboardApi
                    .service_url}/bus?method=${widgetData
                    .graph
                    .data_type}&interval=${widgetData
                    .graph
                    .data_range}&ids=${widgetData
                    .measurements
                    .map(m => m.id)
                    .join(',')}&from=${moment(new Date(widgetData.graph.time_range.start))
                    .format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]')}&to=${moment(new Date(widgetData.graph.time_range.end))
                    .format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]')}&offset=0&count=20`;
            }

            chart
                .dataSource
                .events
                .on("parseended", (ev) => {

                    var data = ev.target.data;
                    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        data[i]
                            .measurements
                            .map(m => {
                                let foundMeas = widgetData
                                    .measurements
                                    .find(measurement => measurement.id === m.id);
                                data[i][foundMeas.id] = m.value;
                                let t = new Date(data[i].date);
                                data[i]['date'] = t;
                            });
                    }

                    this.refreshReq = setTimeout(() => {

                        if (widgetData.graph.time_range.last) {
                            chart.dataSource.url = `${DashboardApi
                                .service_url}/bus?method=${widgetData
                                .graph
                                .data_type}&interval=${widgetData
                                .graph
                                .data_range}&ids=${widgetData
                                .measurements
                                .map(m => m.id)
                                .join(',')}&from=${moment(new Date(new Date().getTime() - timeEnum[widgetData.graph.time_range.range] * widgetData.graph.time_range.time))
                                .format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]')}&to=${moment(new Date())
                                .format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]')}&offset=0&count=20`;
                        } else {
                            chart.dataSource.url = `${DashboardApi
                                .service_url}/bus?method=${widgetData
                                .graph
                                .data_type}&interval=${widgetData
                                .graph
                                .data_range}&ids=${widgetData
                                .measurements
                                .map(m => m.id)
                                .join(',')}&from=${moment(new Date(widgetData.graph.time_range.start))
                                .format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]')}&to=${moment(new Date(widgetData.graph.time_range.end))
                                .format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]')}&offset=0&count=20`;
                        }

                        chart
                            .dataSource
                            .load();
                    }, widgetData.graph.request_interval);
                });

            var categoryAxis = chart
                .xAxes
                .push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
            categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "date";
            categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 60;
            categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0.5;
            categoryAxis.startLocation = 0.5;
            categoryAxis.endLocation = 0.5;

            categoryAxis.events.on('startchanged', (e) => {
                console.log(e.target.minZoomed);
            })

            chart
                .yAxes
                .push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

            chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
            chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
            chart.legend.fontSize = 11;
            chart.legend.draggable = true;
            chart.legend.resizable = true;
            chart.legend.marginBottom = 12;
            chart.legend.fontFamily = "Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif";

            let scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();

            let tempSeries;
            if (widgetData.graph.type === 'Line') {
                widgetData
                    .measurements
                    .map((m, i) => {
                        tempSeries = chart
                            .series
                            .push(new am4charts.LineSeries());

                        tempSeries.dataFields.valueY = m.id;
                        tempSeries.dataFields.dateX = "date";
                        tempSeries.name = m.name;

                        tempSeries.strokeWidth = 1;
                        tempSeries.fillOpacity = 1;

                        var gradient = new am4core.LinearGradient();
                        gradient.addColor(chart.colors.getIndex(i), 0.2);
                        gradient.addColor(chart.colors.getIndex(i), 0);
                        tempSeries.fill = gradient;

                        tempSeries.tooltipText = "{name}: {valueY.value}";
                        tempSeries.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
                        tempSeries.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color(chart.colors.getIndex(i));

                        scrollbarX
                            .series
                            .push(tempSeries);
                    });
            } else {
                widgetData
                    .measurements
                    .map((m, i) => {
                        tempSeries = chart
                            .series
                            .push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());

                        tempSeries.dataFields.valueY = m.id;
                        tempSeries.dataFields.dateX = "date";
                        tempSeries.name = m.name;

                        tempSeries.strokeWidth = 1;

                        tempSeries.tooltipText = "{name}: {valueY.value}";

                        scrollbarX
                            .series
                            .push(tempSeries);
                    });
            }

            chart.scrollbarX = scrollbarX;

            chart.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu();
            chart.exporting.filePrefix = 'ASYA';
            chart.exporting.menu.items = [
                {
                    "label": "...",
                    "menu": [
                        {
                            "label": "Görüntü",
                            "menu": [
                                {
                                    "type": "png",
                                    "label": "PNG"
                                }, {
                                    "type": "jpg",
                                    "label": "JPG"
                                }, {
                                    "type": "gif",
                                    "label": "GIF"
                                }, {
                                    "type": "svg",
                                    "label": "SVG"
                                }, {
                                    "type": "pdf",
                                    "label": "PDF"
                                }
                            ]
                        }, {
                            "label": "Data",
                            "menu": [
                                {
                                    "type": "json",
                                    "label": "JSON"
                                }, {
                                    "type": "csv",
                                    "label": "CSV"
                                }, {
                                    "type": "xlsx",
                                    "label": "XLSX"
                                }
                            ]
                        }, {
                            "label": "Yazdır",
                            "type": "print"
                        }, {
                            "label": "Tablo",
                            "type": "custom",
                            options: {
                                callback: function () {
                                    // create a table
                                    var holder = document.createElement("div");
                                    holder.className = "chart-data";

                                    var table = document.createElement("table");
                                    table.id = 'chart-data-table'

                                    holder.appendChild(table);
                                    var tr,
                                        td;

                                    if (chart.data.length > 0) {
                                        for (var x = 0; x < chart.data.length; x++) {
                                            if (x == 0) {
                                                tr = document.createElement("tr");
                                                table.appendChild(tr);
                                                td = document.createElement("th");
                                                td.innerHTML = 'Zaman';
                                                td.style.backgroundColor = '#7daa7f';
                                                tr.appendChild(td);

                                                let measurementsArr = chart
                                                    .data[0]
                                                    .measurements
                                                    .map(m => widgetData.measurements.find(measurement => measurement.id === m.id))

                                                measurementsArr.map((m, i) => {
                                                    td = document.createElement('th');
                                                    td.innerHTML = m.name;
                                                    td.style.backgroundColor = chart
                                                        .colors
                                                        .getIndex(i);
                                                    tr.appendChild(td);
                                                })
                                            }

                                            tr = document.createElement("tr");
                                            table.appendChild(tr);
                                            td = document.createElement("td");
                                            td.className = "row-title";

                                            let time = chart.data[x].date;
                                            td.innerHTML = `${oneToTwoDigitConv(time.getDate())}/${oneToTwoDigitConv(time.getMonth() + 1)}/${oneToTwoDigitConv(time.getFullYear())} ${oneToTwoDigitConv(time.getHours())}:${oneToTwoDigitConv(time.getMinutes())}:${oneToTwoDigitConv(time.getSeconds())}`;

                                            tr.appendChild(td);

                                            chart
                                                .data[x]
                                                .measurements
                                                .map(m => {
                                                    td = document.createElement('td');
                                                    td.innerHTML = m.value;
                                                    tr.appendChild(td);
                                                })
                                        }

                                    } else {
                                        tr = document.createElement("tr");
                                        tr.innerHTML = Translator.t('widget.no.measurement.data')
                                        table.appendChild(tr);
                                    }

                                    chart
                                        .chartContainer
                                        .openModal(holder.outerHTML, 'asdasdasd');
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            "label": "Ayarlar",
                            "type": "custom",
                            options: {
                                callback: function () {
                                    onChangeSettings();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]

            this.chart = chart;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }, 200);
}
```

Comment: I am having the same problem.  In my case, it appears to be caused by clearing the data using `chart.data = []` and then adding new data via `.addData()`.  I can put together a CodePen if need be.

Answer (score 4):

The `keepSelection` property seems to affect this.  See [info here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/dateaxis/#keepSelection_property).

Try adding this to your code:

```
categoryAxis.keepSelection = true;
```

Comment: Dudeee. You saved me, searching for this around a hour now and tried so many things comes to end. Thanks mate